Postman Authentication returns sign-in Page in code with white screen
When I request thru web-browser manually I can sign in and I get json response.
But I have tried to do the same but thru postman its not working.
Until I applied oauth2 authentication into my app postman requests has been working.
This is the response I received.
enter image description here
This is my variables.
Postman variables
I can share every information needed to find the problem. I have never had issues with the postman before I don't know what to provide now.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
